# Wix multiple products

Tags: installation, wix, product

this is a general question about wix. 
Our product is split in something like this:

- Common Files
- A specific files
- B specific files
- C specific files
  ...

would like to get:

Installation Kit : full
Common Files
Specific : A , B, C ....

Installation Kit : version A :
Common Files
Specific : A

Installation Kit : version B : 
Common Files
Specific : B

Installation Kit : mixed version A,B :
Common Files
Specific : A,B

in fact we have a full installation file and some "subset" installations to avoid the complete distrubution of unrelated files.

It is something like having "Office Professional Edition" and single "Word package" and "Excel package".I've seen that office installation was done with wix so I suppose this could be managed.

What could be the best way to do this? At least I would like to mantain a single wix file.
Also I would like that any of the installation packages could remove/upgrade a previous version of any of the other packages.

Question: **What could be the best way to obtain this using Wix**?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can achieve this using wixlib approach. You should compile the separate parts of your solution into libraries, called wixlibs. Use [lit.exe](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/lit.htm) for this.

Later, when you build exact kit (version A or B), you provide to the linker ([light.exe](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/light.htm)) a set of necessary wixlib files. For instance, a.wixlib and common.wixlib for installation kit version A.